# $V$ seperable implies $\mathscr{L}(V,W)$ is seperable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a seperable Banach space and $W$ some arbitrary Banach space.

Is $\mathscr{L}(V,W):=\lbrace A: V\rightarrow W | A\text{ is linear and bounded}\rbrace$ again seperable?

Comment: $V=\mathbb{C}$ and $W=\ell^\infty.$

Comment: $V=\ell^1$ and $W=\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Jochen actually very obvious, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple counter example from Jochen, $\ell^\infty= \mathscr{L}(\ell^1,\mathbb{C})$, absolutely answers the question.